# Laravel/JWT token When Does The Token Become Blacklisted?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, php-7

When there is no activity for a certain time, the application sometimes throws `TokenBlacklistedException`. The token expires in a year, so it is not definitely expiration.

It often happens after new deployment.

When does the token exactly become blacklisted?

Any reference or explaination would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

I am using `https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth`

Comment: Hi! Rather than [edit]ing just to include politeness, try to think of more details that might help us to help you. Is there a particular library or setting you're using for the JWT, or is this default Laravel functionality? Is there any code or settings you can show us? Are there any references you've already checked that were relevant but didn't help? Does the exception have a message with any details in? Does it get thrown from a particular point in your application? Have you been able to reliably reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is from the documentation page of [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Blacklists/get_tokens). Please take a look the page for more detailed information.

> The JWT spec provides the jti field as a way to prevent replay attacks. Though Auth0 tokens do not currently return a jti, you can blacklist a jti to prevent a token being used more than X times. In this way you are kind of implementing a nonce (think of the token's signature as the nonce). If a token gets stolen, it should be blacklisted (or the nth token that has been issued after it) and wait for it to expire.

I also find this [post](https://auth0.com/blog/blacklist-json-web-token-api-keys/) very informative about blacklisting a token, hope this helps.

Cheers!